# ¿Existen otros sustantivos como "boleada" para la acción de lustrar el calzado?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, sustantivos, méxico

Viendo la película de [Coco](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2380307/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) por n-ésima vez, me di cuenta del uso del sustantivo *boleada*, definido como de uso en México:

> **[boleada](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=boleada)**.
>
> I. 1. f. *Mx.* Lustrado del calzado.

El oficio del [limpiabotas](https://dle.rae.es/limpiabotas), aunque entiendo que está prácticamente en desuso al menos donde yo vivo, es conocido aunque ahora sea solo por la gente de una cierta edad; sin embargo, no sabía que existía un sustantivo específico para la acción que de lustrado del calzado que ejerce el limpiabotas.

En la película se usa en frases como estas (no las reproduzco de forma exacta, solo de memoria):

> —Solo te pedí una boleada, no que me contaras tu vida.
>
> —No más boleadas en la plaza, [mijo](https://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=mijo).

En España si yo tuviera que reproducir estas frases diría "se acabó el limpiar botas en la plaza" o "solo te he pedido que me limpies los zapatos", perdiendo todas mis opciones de ganar un [translation-golf](/questions/tagged/translation-golf) contra alguien de México. :-)

¿Existen sustantivos similares, de uso en otros países, que ilustren esta misma acción de lustrado del calzado?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Respuesta *wiki*, siéntete libre de editarla y añadir cualquier información relevante para responder a la pregunta.</sup>

---

El propio DLE recoge *lustrada* como de uso en varios países de Hispanoamérica:

> **[lustrada](https://dle.rae.es/lustrada)**
>
> 1. f. *Chile, C. Rica, Ec., Guat., Méx., Nic., Pan., Par., Perú y Ven.* Acción de lustrar algo, especialmente el calzado.